# Wordpress Search - changing search URL breaks special characters

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Problem: the default Wordpress search results URL looks like:

```
https://example.com/?s=search_query
```

Not exactly the prettiest format. Preferred format:

```
https://example.com/search/search+query
```

Looks better, easier to link to, more user-friendly.

Found solution:

```
# Change WordPress search URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \\?s=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1/? [NC,R,L]
```

New problem: search queries that include non-alpha characters (such as the ", [, ', etc) break the search function - entering **search " query** (or **25" widget**) produces "0 Results for: "search %22 query"

Question: how do I fix the redirect to properly process characters such as double-quotes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using other method, Paste the following in your theme's functions.php

```
function wpb_change_search_url() {
    if ( is_search() && ! empty( $_GET['s'] ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url( "/search/" ) . urlencode( get_query_var( 's' ) ) );
        exit();
    }   
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpb_change_search_url' );
```

Check out the ref link for more https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-change-the-default-search-url-slug-in-wordpress/

Comment: I tried that first, but it had zero effect. Definitely added to functions.php, successfully saved & uploaded, but the URL didn't change. And I don't know enough about WP to trace why it's not loading :/  ...any ideas?